JSONPath "$[length(@.foo)]" fails to return array length when tested via json-everything library
This seems like a simple use case. We are trying to obtain the number of items in an array using the JSONPath function length().
The test object is:
{
   "array": [1,2,3]
}

The JSONPath that were tested include:
$[length(@.foo)]

and
$.foo.length()

In both cases, the result via the json-everything library test page is "Path is invalid":
We are currently using the Newtonsoft.Json library which does not seem to support JSONPath aggregate or filtering functions.
We were encouraged to try the json-everything library thank to this comment on GitHub which claims that length() is supported.
The json-everything release notes shows that this function should be supported as of version 0.30.
Thanks for your help.

I haven't used this, but here is the length() Function Extension documentation in the RFC they claim to support. Is that of any help? It sounds like it's only for filtering based on the length, not just getting the length.

in the link you pointed to, they mention the opposite: ".length has been replaced by length() function.", ie, .length() doesn't exist anymore since v0.30. you need to use the length() function.

Hello, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  Might you please [edit] your question to include your JSON and path expression (and code if any) as text rather than as a screenshot?  For why, see Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? for why.  A [mcve] showing some code that does not work as well would increase your chances of getting an answer, see [ask] for details.  Thanks!

Question has been updated with code in place of screenshots.
I've updated the test path based on the feedback from David Conrad and Ofri Cofri; however, we are still getting the same result.
We are still not getting the expected result.

According to the spec, all functions (including length()) are only valid inside filter expressions.  There are some issues (that will be further discussed if a JSON Path 2.0 is ever developed) that discuss using a function outside of filter expressions, but that didn't make it into the spec's first release.
Because of that, expressions like $[length(@.foo)] and $.foo.length() are invalid.
A valid use of the length() function is something like $.foo[?length(@) > 5], which would find all children of foo which themselves have more than 5 children.
Extending your example,
{
   "array": [1,2,3],
   "obj": { "foo": 1, "bar": 2, "baz": 3 },
   "longer": [1,2,3,4,5],
   "not-array": 3
}

the path $[?length(@) == 3] would select the nodes at $.array and $.obj because their values are containers with 3 items, but it wouldn't select $.longer or $.not-array because their values aren't containers with 3 items.
My suggestion for $[length(@.foo)] is to use a negative index: $[-1], and for $.foo.length(), use $.foo and just count the results in code.

Thank you for your reply, Greg. Our application is such that the JSONPaths are entirely user-configurable. I was hoping that JSONPath could compute aggregate values. We will have to add an extra configuration points to feed the results of the JSONPath resolution through an aggregation function.

No, JSON Path is a querying syntax, but it doesn't support aggregates or calculated values.  It's quite simple.  I believe something like JMES Path does support those things, though.
